# Reference many columns of pandas DataFrame at once

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a *n* ⨉ *p* matrix of *n* samples of a single feature of *p* dimension (for example a word2vec element, so that *p* is of the order of ~300). I can create each column programatically, eg. with `features = ['f'+str(i) for i in range(p)]` and then appending to an existing dataframe.

Since they represent a single feature, how can I reference all those columns later on? I can assign `df.feature = df[features]` which works, but it breaks when I slice the dataset: `df[:x].feature` results in an exception.

Example:

```
df = pre_exisiting_dataframe() # such that len(df) is n
n,p = 3,4
m = np.arange(n*p).reshape((n,p))
fs = ['f'+str(i) for i in range(p)]
df_m = pd.DataFrame(m)
df_m.columns = fs
df = pd.concat([df,df_m],axis=1) # m is now only a part of df
df.f = df[fs]
df.f # works: I can access the whole m at once
df[:1].f # crashes
```

Comment: `df.f = df[fs]` By doing this, you are introducing a new attribute called f and that's an attribute of df, not its slices. Try `df.ix[:1, fs]`

Comment: Right, but `fs` is local and I would like to bind its information to `df`.

Comment: Doesn't `df.f = df[fs]` cause your `fs` columns to be repeated twice? Also, IMHO, this is weird way of going about indexing. `fs` will be constant for all _n_ samples, and can be reused. What exactly are you trying to achieve on a bigger picture? Perhaps there is an easier way of implementing your algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use `df.f = df[fs]`. It may lead to undesired and surprising behaviour if you try to modify the data frame. Instead, I'd consider creating hierarchical columns as in the below example.

Say, we already have a preexisting  data frame `df0` and another one with features:

```
df0 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(4).reshape(2,2), columns=['A', 'B'])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10, 16).reshape(2,3), columns=['f0', 'f1', 'f2'])
```

Then, using the `keys` argument to `concat`, we create another level in columns:

```
df = pd.concat([df0, df1], keys=['pre', 'feat1'], axis=1)
df
Out[103]: 
  pre    feat1        
    A  B    f0  f1  f2
0   0  1    10  11  12
1   2  3    13  14  15
```

The subframe with features can be accessed as follows:

```
df['feat1']
Out[104]: 
   f0  f1  f2
0  10  11  12
1  13  14  15

df[('feat1', 'f0')]
Out[105]: 
0    10
1    13
Name: (feat1, f0), dtype: int64
```

Slicing on rows is straightforward. Slicing on columns may be more complicated:

```
df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice['feat1', :]]
Out[106]: 
  feat1        
     f0  f1  f2
0    10  11  12
1    13  14  15
df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice['feat1', 'f0':'f1']]
Out[107]: 
  feat1    
     f0  f1
0    10  11
1    13  14
```

To modify values in the data frame, use `.loc`, for example `df.loc[1:, ('feat1', 'f1')] = -1`. ([More on hierarchical indexing, slicing etc.](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html))

It's also possible to append another frame to `df`.

```
# another set of features
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(100, 108).reshape(2,4), columns=['f0', 'f1', 'f2', 'f3'])

# create a MultiIndex:
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['feat2'], df2.columns])

# append
df[idx] = df2

df
Out[117]: 
  pre    feat1         feat2               
    A  B    f0  f1  f2    f0   f1   f2   f3
0   0  1    10  11  12   100  101  102  103
1   2  3    13  -1  15   104  105  106  107
```

To keep a nice layout, it's important that `idx` have the same numbers of levels as `df.columns`.

Comment: Exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. Thanks!